# Scalar QCD with yukawa interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, group-representations

Considering
$$ \mathcal{L}_0= -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu,a}F^a_{\mu\nu} + \bar\psi(i\not{D} - M)\psi  + (D_\mu\phi)^2 - m\phi^2 -P(\phi) $$ 
$$ \mathcal{L}= \mathcal{L}_0 + \lambda \bar\psi T^a\psi  \phi^a  $$

where P is a quartic invariant polynomial of scalar field $\phi$ that transforms in the adjoint representation of some gauge group G. Is this lagrangian strictly renormalizable? Using feynman rules i can build this

[image]

and so i guess that the lagrangian needs a cubic scalar selfinteraction to absorb this divergence. Is this diagram possible or not?Thanks

Comment: $8\otimes 8\otimes 8$ contains two singlets, so it already is in your $P(\phi)$ no?

Comment: P($\phi$) is a quartic interaction term and transforms in $8 \otimes 8\otimes 8\otimes 8$

Comment: Quartic polynomial includes cubic and quadratic invariant terms. You should call it a *monomial*, otherwise, but I doubt a sane model builder would exclude cubic and quadratic terms, the latter already including the thus superfluous mass term.

Comment: I have the explcit term $P(\phi)=\alpha d^{abcd} \phi^a \phi^b \phi^c \phi^d + \beta (\phi^a \phi^a)^2$ i'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: Oh,  OK, I'd say "quadrilinear invariant terms" or something. Yes, a cubic invariant term will then be induced by renormalization, and there is no symmetry in the tree Lagrangian preventing it. (You might imagine a $\phi \to -\phi$ symmetry, but the Yukawa term breaks it, and it is precisely this term wich enters in the loop. )

Comment: Ok thanks, but what about the diagram that i draw? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes; it appears that way; that's what I refer to above. Amounts to the induced cubic term.